# sp_dboption in SQL server 2012 for Published property

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, database-replication, transactional-replication

Currently working on migrating SQL server from 2008 to 2012 project. We aware that sp_dboption is deprecated and it will not work in SQL server 2012. In 2008, had code to set the value for Published property.

```
EXEC master..sp_dboption DBName, published, TRUE
```

In 2012, below query is not working. I think i am using incorrect property name 'PUBLISHED'.

```
ALTER DATABASE DBName SET PUBLISHED ON
```

Please help me on the same.

Answer (score 1):

> To modify database options that are associated with replication (merge
>   publish, published, subscribed), use sp_replicationdboption.

[sp_replicationdboption (Transact-SQL)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188769(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
exec sp_replicationdboption @dbname = 'DBName',
@optname = 'publish',
@value = 'true'
```